# Javascript onclick won´t work at first click

Tags: javascript

I´ve got this function:

```
    <script>
  function bookmark() {
    var element = document.getElementById("bookmark");

    if (element.innerHTML === "Bookmark") {
      element.classList.add("bookmarked");
      element.innerHTML = "Bookmarked";
    } else {
      element.classList.remove("bookmarked");
      element.innerHTML = "Bookmark";
    }
  }
</script>
```

And it works good, it toggles the class "bookmarked" and switch the text from "Bookmark" to "Bookmarked".

But the thing is that it won´t work at first click, and I don´t find it functional. Does anyone knows what am I missing?

```js
      function bookmark() {
        var element = document.getElementById("bookmark");

        if (element.innerHTML === "Bookmark") {
          element.classList.add("bookmarked");
          element.innerHTML = "Bookmarked";
        } else {
          element.classList.remove("bookmarked");
          element.innerHTML = "Bookmark";
        }
      }
```

```css
button {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 56px;
  width: 204px;
  border-radius: 33.5px;
  border: 0px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bookmark {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.05);
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

.bookmark:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.05);
}

.bookmarked,
.bookmarked:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<button class="float-end bookmark" id="bookmark" onclick="bookmark()">
          Bookmark
        </button>
```

Comment: use innerText instead of innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are added before the button text "Bookmark". You can use the trim() function to remove the space then compare. Change the below line.

```
if (element.innerHTML.trim() === "Bookmark")
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the white space using `trim()`

```js
function bookmark() {
  var element = document.getElementById("bookmark");
  if (element.innerHTML.trim() === "Bookmark") {
    element.classList.add("bookmarked");
    element.innerHTML = "Bookmarked";
  } else {
    element.classList.remove("bookmarked");
    element.innerHTML = "Bookmark";
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 56px;
  width: 204px;
  border-radius: 33.5px;
  border: 0px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bookmark {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.05);
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

.bookmark:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.05);
}

.bookmarked,
.bookmarked:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<button class="float-end bookmark" id="bookmark" onclick="bookmark()">
          Bookmark
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "innerHTML" field for comparison. Use classList.contains() method. and check if you have the class assigned or not.
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0):

First thing i notice is that you are selecting the HTML element inside the fn()

```
    function bookmark() {
        var element = document.getElementById("bookmark");
    }
```

what i think you should do is select the element first and then on the button click event run the subsequent function

here is a alternative to your way
PS: you only need to update your script and nothing else

**Step 1:** Find the element by id **Assuming that there is just one such element else you can do this using querySelectorAll as well**

**Step 2:** Add **Click** eventListener to that element.

**Step 3:** Run your Fn() Code

```
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("bookmark");

if (element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.innerHTML === "Bookmark") {
      e.classList.add("bookmarked");
      e.innerHTML = "Bookmarked";
    } else {
      e.classList.remove("bookmarked");
      e.innerHTML = "Bookmark";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```